# Setting constant labels positions in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, visualisation

I've been trying to figure out how to stop the labels from moving when dragging the map with the cursor.

[image: here is what happens]

Is it possible to prevent this from happening? I am new to QGIS and don't really know what to try to fix this.

Comment: Please provide your current label settings, as well as a description of how you expect the labels to behave.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- In Labels tab in Layer Styling (<kbd>F7</kbd>), open the **Placement** tab.
- Click the Settings button below **Label Anchoring**.
- Select  ***Use Entire Line*** for ***Clipping*** and ***Strict*** for ***Placement Behavior***.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Another option would be to use the datadefined attributes to set the x and y, but that should be functionnally similar.

Comment: @Alrl You can add this useful option in details as a new answer.